# Spring validation and @Valid

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/eusers", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String createEUser(@Valid @RequestBody EUser e, BindingResult result){
            if(result.hasErrors()){
                return "error";
            }
            //EUser creation and adding to a DB
            return "OK";
    }
```

EUser.java is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class EUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Max(5)
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The issue is when I even pass the pararmeter which contains less than 5 characters (`"asd"` in the case) I got the validation error message:

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'euser' on field 'name': rejected value [asd]; 
codes [Max.user.name,Max.name,Max.java.lang.String,Max]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [euser.name,name]; 
arguments []; default message [name],5]; 
default message [must be less than or equal to 5]
```

But the `asd` string is valid! What's wrong? In the error message we can see that `rejected value [asd];`. Why?

Comment: Don't use @Max for Strings validation,try to make use of @Length(min = 1, max = 5) or @Size(max=5) annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bean validation does not specify use of `@Max`for strings. From hibernate validation [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bean-constraints.html#validator-defineconstraints-spec):

> Hibernate Validator allows some constraints to be applied to more data types than required by the Bean Validation specification (e.g. @Max can be applied to Strings). Relying on this feature can impact portability of your application between Bean Validation providers.

So, try use `@Size`, like this, for compliance with all providers:

```
@Column
@Size(max=5)
private String name;
```

Answer (score 3):

`@Max` is for numbers. You should use [`@Size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) to validate string length.